# Several Performance Issues after migrating from .NET 1.1 to .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb6

We migrated an ASP.NET 1.1 web application to 4.0 and since then the performance has been getting worse day by day. Pages take about 5-6 minutes to load, even a simple one. Classic ASP goes fast as the wind, but ASPX.. oh my. Yesterday I let Debug Diagnostics running an analysis on the machine and will see it tomorrow. Besides, I searched for similar problems and found these 2 threads with *possible* solutions -- we use lots of VB6 dlls as unmanaged code to do all sort of stuff. Could they be the problem? What do you guys think? In the second link, the question author answered that he found the problem - it was a recordsetclass update method that was making performance go down.

Any ideas?

[Unexpected behaviour after migrating from .NET 1.1 to 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953377/unexpected-behaviour-after-migrating-from-net-1-1-to-3-5)

[Performance issues after upgrading from asp.net 1.1 to 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815984/performance-issues-after-upgrading-from-asp-net-1-1-to-3-5/20760329#20760329)

Comment: There is only one way to solve performance problems in migrating from ASP.NET 1.1 to ASP.NET 4.0. It's the same way to solve _all_ performance problems: measure the performance, find out where the code and/or database are slow, then fix it. You don't seem to have done the measuring part yet.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out what was happening, is case anyone wants to know. There was a call to Environment.Stacktrace (the getter method) that was hanging heavily, besides being called at every database access (wow) -- almost 100% of IIS threads were blocked by this call. Not sure the reason, but this call used to work fine in .NET 1.1 and I couldn't find any clues about it.

btw, sorry about saying 'thanks', I'm new around here, it was my first question - won't happen again.

Comment: Getting a stack trace is an expensive operation that should really only be done when absolutely necessary, such as in debug logging or in exception handling.  Out of curiosity, why was a stack trace being pulled during database access?  Just a debug tool left in by accident?

Comment: I don't have any idea why this code is there -- probably a debug tool left by accident, as you said.. (it's legacy code) but it used to work fine in .NET 1.1 so it never called our attention. Everyday we keep finding surprises in this source code that only God knows the reasons.